# Proving existence of $\gcd$: Artin exercise 2.3.3

Tags: proof-explanation, gcd-and-lcm

I am trying to solve this exercise in Artin.

> (a) Define the greatest common divisor of a set $\{a_1, \ldots, a_n\}$ of $n$ integers. Prove that it exists, and that it is an integer combination of $a_1, \ldots, a_n$.
>
> (b) Prove that if the greatest common divisor of $\{a_1, \ldots, a_n\}$ is $d$, then greatest common divisor of $\{a_1/d, \ldots, a_n/d\}$ is $1$.

I am having difficulty getting started, and am really just looking for a hint and some clarifications on interpretation. My thoughts on this at the moment are:

1) My first instinct is to induct on $n$. I don't think we can define the $\gcd$ of an empty set or of a single element, so the base case would would have to be $n = 2$.

2) It doesn't seem that I have any information on these integers. Can we define the $\gcd$ of $0$ or negative integers? Surely the $\gcd$ itself is greaeter than or equal to $1$.

3) I cannot figure out how to 'prove' existence. If we have two integers, the $\gcd$ "exists by definition." If the integers are relatively prime, their $\gcd$ is $1$. If not, there exists some integer $d > 1$ that divides both. There's certainly a finite number of such elements because the distance between any two integers is finite, so taking the maximum gives the $\gcd$.

4) The $n \implies n + 1$ inductive step seems to just be invoking this same $n = 2$ argument I just made.

Comment: The gcd of an empty set is $1$, and $\gcd(\{n\})$  is $n$.

Comment: @MJD  If I were to define $\gcd\emptyset$, I would set it to be $0$.  This is to make sure that $\gcd (A\cup B)=\gcd(\gcd A,\gcd B)$ for all sets $A,B\subseteq\Bbb Z$.  After all, the ideal generated by $\emptyset$ of $\Bbb Z$ is the zero ideal.  (Likewise, $\operatorname{lcm}\emptyset$ should be defined to be $1$.)

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:Take the subset generated $S$ by $a_1,..,a_n$ and the smallest positive element is $d$.

$d$ divides $a_i$ if not $a_i=b_id+r, r<d$, $ r=d-b_ia_i\in S$ contradiction. 
Let $c$ be a common divisor, $a_i=c_ic$, since $d\in S, d=b_1a_1+...+b_na_n=b_1c_1c+...+b_nc_nc=(b_1c_1+..+b_nc_n)c$ and $c$ divides $d, c\leq d$.

Comment: How do I know that there exists a positive element? It seems that all of the $a_i$ could be negative.

Comment: Start with all the $a_i$ positive, then work with the absolute value